# Understanding this C# code, I mean only the code, not the theory of Entropy

Tags: c#

I finally found a code possibly working Shannon Entropy calculation, but as I don't fully understand C# at all, could someone help me fully grasp it please? I mean purely understand the code, NOT what it is doing. I do understand Delphi, if you ask.

```
public static double ShannonEntropy(string s)
{
    var map = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!map.ContainsKey(c))
            map.Add(c, 1);
        else
            map[c] += 1;
    }

    double result = 0.0;
    int len = s.Length;
    foreach (var item in map)
    {
        var frequency = (double)item.Value / len;
        result -= frequency * (Math.Log(frequency) / Math.Log(2));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "What" about the code is unclear? There is a method, two loops over sequences, some variables with assignments, a Dictionary and some math.. very procedural, like Delphi.

Comment: @user2864740 the Dictionary is unclear to me

Comment: It has the same role as a TDictionary in Delphi: http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/using-t-dictionary-hash-tables-in-delphi.htm - see http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx , etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a function called `ShannonEntropy` which takes a string `s` and returns something of type `double` (basically a floating point number).
2. You instantiate a map (dictionary) of characters -> integers and call it `map`.
3. Loop over every character in the string `s`. During that loop check to see if the character is in our map (`map`). If it is not, map that character to 1. If it is already in the map, increment the value. At the end we'll have a map of each character to a count of how often it appears in `s`.
4. Declare a `double` name `result` and set it 0.
5. Declare an integer called `len` which is the length of the input string.
6. Loop over every character in our map. During the loop we're going to compute the frequency of how often it appears.

   - We declare a variable called `frequency` and set it to the count (the value we stored in the map) divided by the length of the string - so the frequency gets set to the percentage of each character that appears in `s` every time we loop.
   - Now we take the frequency (the percentage the given character appeared) and multiply it by the log (base 2) of the frequency, take the product and subtract it from `result` (which was initially 0).
7. Once we've finished looping we return the `result`.

Answer (score 0):

Var is initializing variable map , new dictionary has added a dictionary to the var . dictionary gives the string or a char value an integer Value, let's say that red = 1 , blue = 2 , green = 3 etc . I think foreach runs the loop for as long as there there are char in string .
You must know if( ) it compiles the code only if the statement inside is true or false as in this case.math.log is a method . then at end we return result . I am not very familiar with c# I am more familiar with c and Java .